# How to set Million separator (') and thousand (.) using cultureinfo in C#

Tags: c#, numbers, number-formatting, cultureinfo

I'm trying to convert a value 9.999.999 to 9'999.999 using cultureinfo in C# but I can't get it works.

How can I do that?

Comment: Hi, show us what you have tried. You are on the right track.

Comment: is `9.999.999` string or decimal?

Comment: It's a string variable

Comment: What if the number has more than 3 groups?

Comment: Is this something that you personally would like to see, or is this the usual way for the culture you are working for?

Comment: I am not sure you can set different group separator in the same formatting with `CultureInfo`. I think you will have to do it with `Regex` or String operation (`String.Replace`, etc). Can you provide us more examples? (for example what do you expect for billions numbers?)

Comment: Which culture uses different separator for thousands an millions?

Comment: i can imagine ... "the customer pays to be a special snowflake"

Answer (score 2):

So it's a string and you want a different group-separator for first groups?

You could replace all but the last dot:

```
string value = "9.999.999";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value);
bool skippedLast = false;

for (int i = sb.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (sb[i] == '.')
    {
        if (!skippedLast)
            skippedLast = true;
        else
            sb[i] = '\'';
    }
}

string desiredOutput = sb.ToString(); // 9'999.999
```

Answer (score 1):

since the default `IFormatProvider` implementations that are shipped with the framework lack the capability you want/need, I suggest implementing the interface yourself

additionally, since `CultureInfo` is not sealed, you can extend the class and provide your implementation to `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` ... all consecutive formatting calls on that thread will use your implementation (unless called with a specific format provider...)

Comment: You also need the `ICustomFormatter`. Perhaps you want to add that to your answer. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icustomformatter(v=vs.110).aspx